# x-for didn't work in Alpine.js with variable reference

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

Here are my Html code, It used to display a list of posts. When click one row, show a dialog with messages in that post.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="panel panel-default" x-data="posts()">
    <div class="panel-heading">Bubbles</div>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <template x-for="(post, index) in posts" x-item="index">
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
                    <span x-text="post.title"></span>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="onCooperationBtnClick($event, post)">Cooperate</button>
                </div>
            </li>
        </template>
    </ul>

    <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keybord="false">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                                aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Dialog</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <template x-if="currentPost" x-for="(message, index) in currentPost.messages" x-item="index">
                        <div>
                            <span x-text="message.content"></span>
                        </div>
                    </template>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" x-model="message" maxlength="50" placeholder="say something">
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn" x-bind:disabled="!message">send</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
</div>
```

My Js code:

```
  function posts() {
    return {
        posts: [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "title": "BBBBBBBBBBBBB",
                "messages": [
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "content": "123123123123",
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "content": "123123123123",
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "AAAAAAAAAA",
                "messages": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "content": "123123123123",
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        currentPost: null,
        dialogOpen: false,
        message: '',
        onCooperationBtnClick($event, post) {
            this.currentPost = post
            $('#dialog').modal('show')
        }
    }
}
```

It should display the message content in the span,but it didn't. Change `message.content` to `index` value, and it worked, and the number of messages matches.
Even more wierd is, when I put `<button @click="console.log(currentPost.messages[0].content)"></button>` in it, It print the correct thing!
so,What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you've got a mix of jQuery and AlpineJs here. What's probably happening is the jQuery is showing the modal before Alpine's reactive properties are updated in the DOM. You'll need to use Alpine's `$nextTick` method to show the modal after Alpine's reactive props are updated:

```
onCooperationBtnClick($event, post) {
    this.currentPost = post

    this.$nextTick(() => {
        $('#dialog').modal('show')
    })
}
```

Ideally you'd remove jQuery here and just toggle the relevant classes needed to display the modal using Alpine.